# SQL Server Query Not Updating Rows from Laravel Application using Update method in Query Builder

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-10

I have a Laravel app connected to an SQL Server database, configured correctly. The database has a 'Customer' table with columns 'customerlink' (PK) and 'CustomerStatus'.

When I run the following code within a method

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->enableQueryLog();

$x = [6891,6892,6893,6894,6895,6896,6897];
DB::connection('sqlsrv')
                ->table('Customer')
                ->wherein('customerlink',$x)
                ->update(['CustomerStatus' => 4]);

$queries = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getQueryLog();
dd($queries); // Output the queries
```

It returns the following query

```
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "update [Customer] set [CustomerStatus] = ? where [customerlink] in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:8 [▼
      0 => 4
      1 => 6891
      2 => 6892
      3 => 6893
      4 => 6894
      5 => 6895
      6 => 6896
      7 => 6897
    ]
    "time" => 123.09
  ]
]
```

However, it appears that the query is correct, but unfortunately, it doesn't affect the rows in the database.
So the Question is: why doesn't the query effect on DB's rows?

1 - I tried this alternative method, which worked

```
foreach ($x as $customer) {
                 DB::connection('sqlsrv')
                    ->table('Customer')
                    ->wherein('customerlink',[$customer])
                    ->update(['CustomerStatus' => 3]);
            }
```

2 - I also checked the memory limit in the php.ini file and increased it to 1024M, but this didn't change the result in the database.

3 - I verified using SQL Server Profiler, and it provided the following result:

```
go
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int',N'update [Customer] set [CustomerStatus] = @P1 where [customerlink] in (@P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8)',4,6891,6892,6893,6894,6895,6896,6897
select @p1
go
```

It's evident that the query is correct and reaches the SQL Server, but it still doesn't affect the database.

4 - When I run this query in SQL Server Management Studio, it works

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int',N'update [Customer] set [CustomerStatus] = @P1 where [customerlink] in (@P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8)',4,6891,6892,6893,6894,6895,6896,6897
```

Could someone please explain what happened and identify any mistakes I may have made?